# How do I add a device driver for DSI panel in mendel (linux-imx)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, google-coral

I am attempting to add a MIPI DSI panel driver to the imx-linux kernel that is part of mendel.  This is for the Google Coral SoM.

Mostly following the steps described here: https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/how-to-add-a-new-panel-with-imx8mm-evk-I-got-some-problem/m-p/885656/thread-id/134161

What I have done so far:

- added the driver source to **drivers/gpu/drm/panel/**, the makefile and kconfig and verified that it builds.
- added the devicetree definition to **fsl-imx8mq-phanbell.dts** like this:

```
&mipi_dsi { 
    panel@0 {
    compatible = "sitronix,st7701s";
    reg = <0>;
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_mipi_dsi_en>;
    reset-gpio = <&gpio4 19 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;  
    dsi-lanes = <2>;
    video-mode = <2>;
    panel-width-mm = <37>;
    panel-height-mm = <65>;
    status = "okay";
    };
```

- checked on the target that **/proc/device-tree/mipi_dsi@30A00000/panel@0/status** is 'okay'

However there is no sign at all of the driver being called - there are debug statements like    `printk(KERN_DEBUG"Enter func %s...\n",__func__);` in the main functions such as *st7701s_panel_probe()*
However, nothing is ever printed at boot or found in dmesg, and there is no activity on the display lines.

Is there a missing step and how can I test that the driver is loaded and called?

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Humn, this I'm actually not sure as we haven't tried a DSI display before, do you see this new settings if you run this?
```
dtc -I fs -O dts /sys/firmware/devicetree/base | tee base.dts
```

Comment: Hi Nam, yes, my dts changes do come through.  But I seem not to have all the configuration needed.  For example in fsl-imx8q-som.dtsi there is a mipi-dsi configuration for Raydium panel (the one intended for the Coral board?).  If I try enabling these sections (&dcss etc) then the board fails to boot.